# Crystal oscillator 3.1 and 3.3 MHz

Tags: oscillator, crystal

Why is it difficult to find crystal oscillators that oscillate at 3.1 MHz and 3.3 MHz?

I searched for hours and couldn't find it.

Can anybody hep me on this?

Comment: Crystal oscillators don't exist at any random frequencies that you can think of, only at most common standard frequencies that can actually be used for some specific application. Why would you need 3.1 MHz and 3.3 MHz to begin with?

Comment: Probably not much demand for them. Consider asking a crystal manufacturer for custom cut crystals if you REALLY need them; they won't be THAT expensive. Otherwise there are plenty of other approaches, like using PLLs to change frequency from some standard frequency.

Comment: can you recomand crystal manufacurer?

I want to build this kind of machine, but there is 3.1 or 33Mhz http://w5jgv.com/rife/2011_Rife_Beam-Ray_System/index.htm

Comment: programmable XO’s are cheap viable option

Comment: The website for the device you are trying to build includes a part list which indicates a programmable oscillator is used. You can buy a similar one or take a MCU dev board that runs fast enough to generate both 3.1 and 3.3 MHz with timers.